# Problem with reading conversion characters in c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stl

I have already some code:

```
std::string str2("Hello\r\n");
 if (str2.find ("\r\n") != std::string::npos)
   Console::WriteLine("Enter!\n");
```

On console screen:
Enter!

All good, but
if we create str2 from xml.GetData() which return string

```
std::string str2(xml.GetData());
 if (str2.find ("\r\n") != std::string::npos)
  Console::WriteLine("Enter!\n");
```

On console screen:
empty

How to parse "\r\n", for instance, from xml.GetData()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how your xml data is treating end-of-line.  It might just be `\n`.  Try searching for just that instead of `\r\n`.

EDIT: Doesn't `GetData()` return the data associated with the current node?  Unless your outside of an actual element/attribute, this might never give a new-line.

Comment: I have already solved this problem. In the "str2.find ("\r\n") " i made fatal error. Do write: str2.find ("\\r\\n")

Answer (score 1):

That obviously depends on your xml class, and you haven't specified which library you're using.  Anyway, you can obviously print out the numeric value of the individual characters in str2 to see if/how newlines are represented/captured: i.e. `(int)str2[i]` for `i` between `0` to `str2.size() - 1` inclusive.

It's very probably simply "\n" without the explicit "\r" (carriage return), it's vaguely possible that both characters are there in the opposite order, or some other token has been substituted.